# Execution time of my application drastically changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, execution-time

I am making an application which is based on posting and downloading images and videos. The problem I'm encountering is that sometimes randomly the execution speed of every method in my app goes rly high and everything happens crazy fast. It is really visible because the starting view of my app is a looped animation and when this occurs the timer of it is ignored and the whole animation just flickers and executes insanely fast. I have no idea what could even be causing this kind of behaviour or where to even look for the cause because it doesn't seem to occur in a specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to profile your application using the Time profiler in the Instruments section.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want some help with this, you may post some of your sourcecode to let people review it and identify the errors.

Second point: as it seems for me, you may be having a problem on the timer event, maybe you're not handling it properly, check this. Can't say much more without some code.